# When to use MySQL over a filesystem "database" when checking for unique strings

Tags: php, mysql, filesystems, lamp

**Note: this is only for the case of checking for unique EXACT MATCH of strings less than 128 char.**

A very common operation in many of my apps is **simply checking for existence of a persistent string** that is either a

- unique username,
- unique filename/URL
- (in general) unique string (UUID for example)

In the past, without thinking much about it, I have just created a standard table in MySQL for keeping track of this.

*I recently was told that this equivalent operation of simply checking for a unique string should probably just be done on the filesystem, check `file_exist()` on a path.*

**My question is, when should one use MySQL vs merely(?) file system?**

---

My naive understanding is that MySQL is designed to index better - but is this only for more complex operations?

I have a few worries:

1. Does PHP `file_exists()` degrade when there are a large number of
   files in a folder? At which point should you "shard" a folder on an
   CentOS or Ubuntu Apache server (actually, I am not sure how dependent on PHP version, OS, web server version this is)?
2. If one needs to do things like list files, does that also come at a high performance cost over just your typical MySQL `SELECT Like '%bla%'` for example?

Lemma: should both systems be created in parallel? The filesystem being used for quick checks and the MySQL system for listing / searches / other operations?

Comment: A database is always preferential to a file system

Comment: It's in the names: MySQL is a relational *database* and is ideal for *data*. A *filesystem* stores *files*. If you want something that's a bit of both, look for an "object store" type database. The key question here is what are you doing beyond checking for the presence of an ID?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Depends on what you're actually storing.

Comment: The performance of an "exists" tests varies wildly depending on operating system, file system, and sometimes other factors. Directories with >1000 files can run slowly on some systems, fine on others. You'll need to benchmark to find out.

Comment: @tadman so... Sharding to new folder when it hits 1000?

Comment: This *really depends* on exactly what you're trying to achieve here. Are these just identifiers? If so, use a database. If this is actually a collection of images or binary data of some kind a filesystem makes sense, but you'd spread those out using, for example, chunks of the UUID itself, like `48bd2391/02fb/4b72/ae73/45f1cca379c1.png`, perhaps even more aggressively depending on how many files you have and how bad your filesystem is at dealing with large directories.

Comment: literally just string lookup for unique existence

Comment: Use a database. Make an index on this column. Problem solved. Note that this depends on doing exact matches, not arbitrary substrings. It's far from clear what "searches" mean in the context you're describing. You may need to elaborate on the problem you're trying to solve vs. what you think you need to do to solve this vaguely defined issue.

Comment: update question. exact match unique() strings

Answer (score 0):

For all those use cases you just need a table that describes each one, and then you can do uniqueness checks against that. The key is to have a `UNIQUE` index on each important column, like:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `index_users_name` (`name`)
);
```

Where it's now trivial to check:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE name=?
```

If you're just looking for exact matches. You can also use `WHERE IN (?,?, ...)` for a list of potential matches.

> Note: You would only use a filesystem if these identifiers have large amounts of binary data associated with them. MySQL's BLOB columns require a lot more work for the server to deliver than a file on disk, plus can complicate your backup strategy. Dumping a 10GB database isn't hard, but dumping a 2TB one requires significant effort even if only one file changed.